# Tawk.to href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())" alternative

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy, tawk.to

I have a website with Tawk.to chat. I writing my Content Security Policy and i need to avoid all inline scripts.

The code looks like this:

HTML

```
<a class="message_button anchor" id="message_button" href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())" title="Üzenjen nekünk!"><img
            alt="Üzenet küldés gomb ikonja" src="img/message_icon.svg" /></a>
```

JS

```
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
        var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async=true;
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5fb64551920fc91564c886eb/default';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();
```

So the problem is with the javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle());

```
$("#message_button").click(function() {
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())");
        });
```

but its kinda the same. I tried to add an eventListener with click and Tawk_API.toggle() but the console said Tawk_API.toggle() is not a function.

Any suggestion? Any alternative for the javascript:void()?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery on() method as an alternative

```
<script>
    
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        
     $( "#message_button" ).on( "click", "a", function(){Tawk_API.toggle();});
     
    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add an eventListener with click and Tawk_API.toggle() but the console said Tawk_API.toggle() is not a function.

It's because you call Tawk_API when API  is loaded yet. It need to use `Tawk_API.onLoad` event, see an example in [Tawk doc](https://developer.tawk.to/jsapi/):

```
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    Tawk_API.toggle();
};
```

You had to do something like that:

```
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    $("#message_button").click(function() {
        Tawk_API.toggle();
    });
};
```

PS: The `$(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())");` construct is an javascript navigation so it's an inline script.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to activate Tawk.to chat window using `onclick` attribute with "Tawk_API.toggle()" value on the button.